# A result about determinants in exterior algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, determinant, multilinear-algebra, exterior-algebra

Let $E,E^*$ be a pair of dual $n$-dimensional vector spaces over a field $\Gamma$ of characteristic zero.

Consider the following result:

**Proposition:** If $\Delta\ne0$ is an $n$-dimensional determinant function on $E$ (that is, $\Delta:E^n\to\Gamma$ is multilinear and alternating), then for any $(n-1)$-dimensional determinant function $\Phi:E^{n-1}\to\Gamma$ on $E$, there is a unique vector $h\in E$ with
$$\Phi(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1})=\Delta(h,x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1})$$
for all $x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1}\in E$. In other words, $\Phi=i_A(h)\Delta$ where $i_A(h):A^n(E)\to A^{n-1}(E)$ denotes the substitution operator on alternating multilinear functions.

This result explains important properties of determinants like the cofactor expansion, and has a natural geometric interpretation--it tells us for example that measuring oriented area in planes in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is (numerically) equivalent to measuring oriented volume relative to a fixed vector.

I'm interested in finding a more abstract and general statement and proof of this result in the language of exterior algebra. So far I have obtained the following result by considering the isomorphism $A(E)\cong\bigwedge E^*$:

**Proposition:** If $v^*\in\bigwedge^n E^*$ and $v^*\ne 0$, then for any $u^*\in\bigwedge^{n-1}E^*$ there is a unique vector $h\in E$ with $i(h)v^*=u^*$, where $i(h):\bigwedge^n E^*\to\bigwedge^{n-1}E^*$ is the insertion operator dual to the left multiplication operator $\mu(h)$:
$$\langle i(h)v^*,u\rangle=\langle v^*,\mu(h)u\rangle=\langle v^*,h\wedge u\rangle\qquad(u\in\textstyle\bigwedge^{n-1}E)$$
*Proof:* If $u^*=0$, we take $h=0$. If $u^*\ne 0$, then since $u^*$ has degree $n-1$ it is decomposable and we may write
$$u^*=x^*_1\wedge\cdots\wedge x^*_{n-1}\qquad(x^*_i\in E^*)$$
Fix $h^*\in E^*$ with $v^*=h^*\wedge u^*$. Let $F^*$ be the span of $x^*_1,\ldots,x^*_{n-1}$, and let $h$ be the basis vector of $(F^*)^{\perp}$ in $E$ with
$$i(h)h^*=\langle h^*,h\rangle=1$$
Since $i(h)$ is an antiderivation with respect to the canonical involution in $\bigwedge E^*$, it follows that
$$i(h)v^*=i(h)(h^*\wedge u^*)=i(h)h^*\wedge u^*-h^*\wedge i(h)u^*=u^*$$
The uniqueness of $h$ is clear.

**Questions:** Is this right? Is there a "better" version?

Comment: The proof can be made more direct by use of coordinates. A "better" version might be the following: Suppose $\omega$ is a nonvanishing $n$-form on an $n$-dimensional manifold $M$. Then the map $F : X(M) \to \Lamba^{n - 1}(M)$ defined by $F(Y) = i_Y\omega$ is a smooth bundle isomorphism. This doesn't require any extra work to prove, but it is quite useful, especially the explicit coordinate formulas.

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff I've been thinking about this again while working on a new video. I like the spirit of your comment but what you wrote is not true (assuming you meant to write $I=h\wedge J$): such $h$ will not exist if $I\ne 0$ but $J=0$, and even when $h$ exists it need not be unique.

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff I'm still looking for a general purpose method to "translate" between facts in the language of determinant functions and facts in the language of exterior algebra which requires no thought to carry out. I feel there should be a method using some subset of (i) universality of determinant functions/exterior powers, (ii) natural isomorphisms between spaces of alternating maps and exterior powers (iii) duality, but I haven't worked out anything satisfying yet.

Comment: @blargoner You're totally right. I'm not entirely sure what I was trying to say, so I'm just going to delete it. Could you give more examples of statements you'd like to translate? Though I think the best *formal* method is going to be exactly what you did here: a determinant function $\Psi$ is an element of $({\bigwedge}^kE)^*$, so there is a unique $u^* \in {\bigwedge}^kE^*$ such that $\Psi(x) = \langle u^*, x\rangle$, and we can translate statements about $\Phi$ to statements about $u^*$.

Comment: I just thought of a slick proof using Poincare duality: if $v \in {\bigwedge}^nE$ then $$i(i(x)y^*)v = x\wedge(i(y^*)v)$$ for any $x \in {\bigwedge}E$ and $y^* \in {\bigwedge}E^*$. Choose the unique $v$ such that $i(v^*)v = i(v)v^* = \langle v^*, v\rangle = 1$. Then $$u^* = i(h)v^* \implies i(u^*)v = i(i(h)v^*)v = h\wedge(i(v^*)v) = h$$ so $h$ is uniquely defined.

Comment: I should comment on what's happening here geometrically.
${\bigwedge}E$ is the algebra of joining lines, and ${\bigwedge}E^*$ is the algebra of intersecting hyperplanes. Nonzero $v^* \in {\bigwedge}^nE^*$ represents the origin, and $u^*\in{\bigwedge}^{n-1}E^*$ represents a line. $i(x^*)y$ is the intersection of the geometric objects $x^*, y$ as represented in ${\bigwedge}E$, and $i(x)y^*$ is the join of geometric objects $x, y^*$ as represented in ${\bigwedge}E^*$...

Comment: ...So $u^*=i(\_)v^*$ is asking the question: what lines, when joined with the origin, yield the line $u^*$? Obviously there is only one line: the line represented by $u^*$.

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff Thanks! I'll digest when I have a free moment.